# Errors configuring UberRush javascript module

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, uber-api

Utilized the UserRUSH API that can be found on this link:

UBERRUSH Javascript API: https://github.com/mjk/uber-rush

Installed (Ubuntu server)  this package by calling

npm install uber-rush

This created node_modules folder.

Received errors below when trying to execute:
1) bower install uber-rush --save
error:
bower ESUDO         Cannot be run with sudo

Additional error details:
Since bower is a user command, there is no need to execute it with superuser permissions.
If you're having permission errors when using bower without sudo, please spend a few minutes learning more about how your system should work and make any necessary repairs.

https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814

You can however run a command with sudo using --allow-root option

2) bower install uber-rush --allow-root
Error:  bower ENOTFOUND     Package uber-rush not found

uber-rush folder in node_modules folder

Comment: As I told you `uber-rush` does not provide bower support. You have to load uber-rush into your app by other way.

Answer (score 0):

Uber-rush can only be installed via NPM. Find out more at https://www.npmjs.com/package/uber-rush